# Cannot deploy EAR on WildFly 8.2.1.Final

Tags: jakarta-ee, deployment, intellij-idea, wildfly, ear

I'm having the following error on Wildfly when trying to deploy an EAR:

```
[standalone@IP:9990 /] deploy /opt/banco_ear.ear
{"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"banco_ear.ear\".STRUCTURE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"banco_ear.ear\".STRUCTURE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment \"banco_ear.ear\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS018740: Failed to mount deployment content
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: VFS000015: Could not create directory for original name 'content' after 10 attempts"}}}}
```

The EAR is generated by Intellij IDEA and I fix all of the dependencies. I'm new with remote deployments, and I find it very difficult.

Here is my application.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd"
             version="6">

    <module id="banco-Web">
        <web>
            <web-uri>web.war</web-uri>
            <context-root>bancoWeb</context-root>
        </web>
    </module>
</application>
```

What is wrong?

Thank's in advance.

**EDIT**

When I run jboss-cli as wildfly user and try to deploy the application (that in local wildfly run's perfectly), the CLI throws the next exception:

```
[standalone@IP:9990 /] deploy /opt/prueba_ear.ear
{"WFLYCTL0062: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"prueba_ear.ear\".WeldStartService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"prueba_ear.ear\".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
javax.enterprise.event.ObserverException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at org.jboss.weld.security.NewInstanceAction.run(NewInstanceAction.java:33)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.Exceptions.rethrowException(Exceptions.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.Exceptions.rethrowException(Exceptions.java:78)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:96)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:78)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInvocationStrategy$SimpleMethodInvocationStrategy.invoke(MethodInvocationStrategy.java:129)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:306)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.java:121)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:284)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:262)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifySyncObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:271)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notify(ObserverNotifier.java:260)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:154)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:148)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:54)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.java:42)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AfterBeanDiscoveryImpl.fire(AfterBeanDiscoveryImpl.java:61)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.deployBeans(WeldStartup.java:420)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:83)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:93)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.sun.faces.flow.FlowCDIContext.<init>(Ljava/util/Map;)V from class com.sun.faces.flow.FlowCDIExtension
    at com.sun.faces.flow.FlowCDIExtension.afterBeanDiscovery(FlowCDIExtension.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:88)
    ... 21 more
"}}}}
```

Comment: This looks to me like the user that is executing wildfly does not have permission to write or create  it's temp and/or work directories

Answer (score 0):

If the files are remotely deployed the deployments goes  to `WILDFLY_HOME/standalone/data/content` and not `WILDFLY_HOME/standalone/deployments` and an entry for the deployment is created in `standalone.xml` which looks like this.

```
 <deployments>
        <deployment name="My-Project.ear" runtime-name="My-Project.ear">
            <content sha1="fb085ab4a36109125517bbe79e3af645170b7814"/>
        </deployment>
 </deployments>
```

It looks like the wildfly user (or which ever user the the deployment is executing) doesn't have write permissions to `WILDFLY_HOME/standalone/data/content` folder.

Comment: thank's for your answer. I'm logged as root in the server, and run ./jboss-cli.sh as root too. But if I run the jboss-cli as wildfly user, the server is returning another error that is an exception. In the first post are the text.

Comment: @Nico: Looks like wildfly user doens't have access , you can use `chmod` command in linux to change the permissions. Running `chmod 777` on standalone folder would be the easiest option. Refer to this link for more details https://www.maketecheasier.com/file-permissions-what-does-chmod-777-means/

Comment: I changed the permissions of the wildfly home folder to 777. And still throws the same exception that I specify in the first post EDIT section. ¿What is `WeldStartService` exception?